# Ansible set fact using an evaluated expression with a variable

Tags: ansible

I am performing an API request and getting JSON back.  I need to use a value in that JSON response for a later task.  I am trying to use set_fact to set the variable.  In that parsing, I am evaluating that expression and in the expression is a variable set previously in the playbook.  I can't figure out how to get that expression to evaluate while also evaluating the variables.  I can hardcode the variable as strings and it works.

```
   - set_fact:
      ip: "{{page_contents.json.variable1 | selectattr('node', 'equalto', 'variable2') | map(attribute='ip') | list | first }}"
```

Comment: Without knowing what your json looks like, the exact info you are trying to get out of it, the error your are getting from your above test... it is impossible to help you.

Comment: above works as is if variable1 and variable2 are the strings I am looking for.  It is really this portion that is the problem `page_contents.json.variable1` .  If I want variable1 to actually be a variable there, I cannot figure out how to get it to evaluate that variable.  I have tried things like json['variable1'] json."{{ variable1 }}" and the other combinations I have been able to think of and search for.

I can hardcode it and it works.  The structure of the json and accessing values is not the problem, it is getting the syntax correct so the variable will evaluate to the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that wrapping the variable in brackets with no quotes works.

```
- set_fact:
      ip: "{{page_contents.json[variable1] | selectattr('node', 'equalto', variable2) | map(attribute='ip') | list | first }}"
```